# Como fazer um join com Django?

Tags: python, django

Estou tentando executar está SQL, utilizando o ORM do Django

```
SELECT * FROM test JOIN questionnaire q ON (q.id = test.questionnaire) WHERE q.discipline = 4;
```

Modelos:

> Test, Questionnaire, Discipline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As consultas em django acontecem de uma maneira muito simples, por exemplo:

```
CHOICE_CLIENTE = (
    ('pessoa_fisica','Pessoa Física'),
    ('pessoa_juridica','Pessoa Jurídica'),
)
class Cliente(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    descricao = models.CharField(mad_length=255)
    tipo_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=CHOICE_CLIENTE)

class CategoriasCliente(models.Model):
    descricao = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cliente = models.ForeignKey (Cliente)
```

Para pegar todas as categorias a partir de um cliente, você faria:

```
cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=cliente_id)
# ou cliente = get_object_or_404(Cliente, id=cliente_id) (boa prática)

categorias = CategoriaCliente.objects.filter(cliente=cliente)
```

Isso iria retornar todas as categorias de um cliente.
Caso você queira fazer um filtro de um atributo do objeto relacionado, você pode fazer:
    categorias = CategoriaCliente.objects.filter(cliente__tipo_cliente='pessoa_juridica')

Existem outras maneiras, mas o básico, é isto.